# how to replace in seires

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to replace ab to next series of xy.
For eg:
I have

```
ab01
Xy01
Xy02
```

Result expected

ab01 to be replaces as Xy03
As the last series of Xy ended at 02.

I want it in SQL

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace with this statement:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn , 'ab', 'Xy')
```

Result: 
 `ab01` will replace to `Xy01`

when you wanna change to Xy03 you have to update with a regular update-statemant:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = 'Xy03'
WHERE myColumn = 'ab01'
```

Result: 
 `ab01` will replace to `Xy03`

Answer (score 0):

First Count all %Xy% in your table that will be kind of a counter and add 1 to it. this will the value for you next counter.

then using update query set value as XyCounter (Xy03)